# В чем ошибка? Cannot open include file: 'atlenc.h'

Tags: node.js

Программа выводит следующую ошибку:

> d:\node_modules\node-sspi\src\NodeSSPI.h(12): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include  file: 'atlenc.h': No such file or directory
>   (compiling source file ..\src

Фрагмент кода:

```
D:\node_modules\node-sspi\build\..\src\*.h
Сборка проектов в этом решении по одному. Чтобы включить параллельную сборку, до
бавьте параметр "/m".
  NodeSSPI.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
d:\node_modules\node-sspi\src\NodeSSPI.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open in
clude file: 'atlenc.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src
\NodeSSPI.cpp) [D:\node_modules\node-sspi\build\NodeSSPI.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\node_modules\node-sspi
gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN !invalid#2 No description
npm WARN !invalid#2 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#2 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sspi@0.2.2 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sspi@0.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\d.belonovsky\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-25T07
_51_58_540Z-debug.log
```

Comment: А какие ваши действия привели к этой ошибке?

Comment: Просто поставил новую версию 10.5.0 node js. И возникла такая ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему откатом до версии node js 9.4. 
На новый сервер ставил новую 10.5.0 версию node js и там видимо требуется установленная платная версия Visual studio в которой доступна библиотека ATL, которая требуется  при установке пакетов npm.